# SharePoint Online free app for Salesforce Chatter App

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am looking to show Salesforce Chatter from SharePoint Online. Are there any free apps available? I tried searching but came with none. Any suggestions. I want to configure one Salesforce Chatter group discussion to be shown on SharePoint Online page within a webpart.

Any suggestions welcome.